# Redis Lua script error: Script attempted to access nonexistent global variable 'print' script

Tags: redis, lua

I'm learning Lua. Given below, is a Lua script to handle some operations

```
local function reverseDb ()
  local key =  KEYS[1]
  local value = ARGV[1]
  redis.call('SREM',key,value)
  return value
end

if pcall(reverseDb) then
  print("success")
else
  print("error")
  redis.call('SADD',key,value)
end
```

While running it throws an error:

```
Script attempted to access nonexistent global variable 'print' script: 39f13cb3bddd638c815531acbc2dc6434a0329c6, on @user_script:17.
```

I don't understand why the error is there. Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis runs Lua script in a sandbox context, and limits the usage of global variables, only parts of global variables/functions are allowed. Obviously, `print` is not allowed.

In your case, you can return the error message instead of printing it.

```
if pcall(reverseDb) then
  return "success"
else
  redis.call('SADD',key,value)
  return "error"
end
```

Comment: could we use `local random = math.random` in lua functions in Redis 7.x?